# BigQuery to have date parameters for use in Looker Studio

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, looker-studio

In LookerStudio there is the ability to have a custom date range.  How can I build my BigQuery to allow for this date range from LookerStudio?  My datasource is Firebase and more specifically ecommerce and items.

Example:

```
SELECT ecommerce FROM `xxx.analytics_375100555.events_20231210`
```

This will return all my ecommerce from December 10, 2023, how can I use a range that will work in LookerStudio as well?  For example Looker Studio will have date ranges like yesterday, last week, this month, etc.

Thanks